# Form end tag not working properly in bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement confirmation delete with bootstrap 4 modal in my laravel project. When modal is open then submit button not working, I inspected browser and showing that, my form end tag was not closed in where am I placed, form end tag placed exactly after form start tag. I am not finding the problem. I checked everywhere in my code.Would someone help me to solve this problem please?

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-body">

    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Blood Group</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @forelse($patients as $patient)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $loop-> index + 1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ $patient->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $patient->address }}</td>
                <td>{{ $patient->blood_group }}</td>
                <td>{{ $patient->type_rh }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ url('admin/patient/'.$patient->id.'/details') }}" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye" style="color:#006400"></i>
                    </a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="{{ url('admin/patient/'.$patient->id.'/edit') }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit" style="color:#e64980"></i>
                    </a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletePatient-{{ $patient->id }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash" style="color:#cc3300"></i>
                    </a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="{{ url('admin/patient/pdf/'.$patient->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>&nbsp;PDF</a>
                </td>
                <!-- Delete Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="deletePatient-{{ $patient->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">

                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                 <h4>Confirm Delete</h4>

                            </div>
                            <form action="{{ url('admin/patient/'.$patient->id.'/delete') }}" method="POST">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Are you sure want to delete this?</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tr>

            @empty

            @endforelse
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>

    </table>
</div>
```

[image: after inspect the browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your DIV that is containing FORM **must** be put inside TD if you want it to be inside TABLE.

**You can't just randomly put div in table - it will not act same as TR or TD and you'll get errors like this due to incorrect HTML**

Note:

Only 2 ways you can correctly use forms in table are:

```
<form>
    <table>...</table>
</form>
```

and

```
<table>
    ...
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            <form>...</form>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the button type like as follow

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/patient/'.$patient->id.'/delete') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
     <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure want to delete this?</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

Submit button should be loks like as follow

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in PHP do it like this:

```
$modalcontent .= '
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_'.$modalid.'">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
</div></div</div>';

echo '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';

$modalcontent .= '
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_'.$modalid.'">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
</div></div</div>';

echo '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';

$modalcontent .= '
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_'.$modalid.'">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
</div></div</div>';
echo '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
..
</tbody></table>

//And now just do:
echo $modalcontent; //-> this will shift all modals out of the table.
```